# EF Migrations when DBContext is locked in by a third paty dll

Tags: entity-framework-6

Given a DBContext which resides in an assembly (foo.dll).  I do not have direct access to the code for foo.dll, which was developed by a third party.  You can assume that the third party has no sight of my database against which I want to run the migrations.

Is it possible for me to perform code first migrations by referencing foo.dll, which I am consuming in my application?

### UPDATE

Any solution the third party can implement,with the exception of exposing the dbcontext class or doing the migrations themselves, will also be fine

Comment: Can you derive from that `DBContext`?

Comment: Any solution the third party can implement,with the exception of exposing  the dbcontext class or doing the migrations themselves, will also be fine.

Comment: Oh...you mean actually executing the migrations, not designing them. Sorry, I misunderstood, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the migration from a project which references the assembly.

So, I would suggest you create a separate project for seeding within your solution which references foo.dll.

Ensure that your database connection string is contained within your web.config or app.config file (You will have to ask the third party the connection string name you should use, or look it up in their documentation if available).

Next, open package manager and run the following commands (use the fqn of the assembly where applicable):

```
enable-migrations -ContextAssemblyName foo; add-migration "initial"; update-database;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `foo.dll` could add a function that would

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<...,...>());
Database.Initialize(true);
```

or some variation of that to trigger the migration.

- [`Database.SetInitializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)
- [`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)
- [`Database.Initialize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.initialize(v=vs.113).aspx)